# declared event which fires, but is not heard

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a vb.net application which contains two forms. One is called "MapComponentForm" and another called "ComponentPropertiesForm". In the MapComponentForm I have defined an event which I want fired when the OK button is clicked. If the ComponentPropertiesForm is open, I want it to "hear" this event and act accordingly. Stepping through the code the event seems to fire as expected but the ComponentPropertiesForm seems to be oblivious to this. I've attached the code from the two forms after stripping out the non relevant code in hopes that someone can tell me why my event goes unheeded. I used the information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/walkthrough-handling-events
in constructing my own code.
Thanks for any suggestions.

```
    Public Class MapComponentForm
        Public Event PartMapped(ByRef status As Boolean)
Public Sub New(shape As Visio.Shape)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        _shape = shape
    End Sub
     Private Sub OkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OkButton.Click
     'If the component properties window is open, refresh it
            If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of ComponentPropertiesForm).Any Then
                RaiseEvent PartMapped(True)
            End If
    end sub
    end class



Public Class ComponentPropertiesForm
        Private WithEvents mPartMap As MapComponentForm
     Private Sub ComponentPropertiesForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            mPartMap = New MapComponentForm(Nothing)
        End Sub
     Private Sub mPartMap_PartMapped(ByRef status As Boolean) Handles mPartMap.PartMapped
            If status = True Then
                MsgBox("something got mapped")
            End If
        End Sub
    end class
```

Comment: To get the event to work the instance of `MapComponentForm` which raises `PartMapped` must be the same which handles it. You create a new instance in the ctor which is doubtly the form shown in the UI. Inject the form to ComponentPropertiesForm instead of creating a new one.

Comment: are you saying that an event raised by one form cannot be acted upon in a different form? that is what I need to do.

Comment: It's not that one form can't handle an event of another form. It's that if a form is to handle an event of another form then it must have a reference to the actual form object that raises the event, not a different form object of the same type. Inside `ComponentPropertiesForm` you are creating an instance of `MapComponentForm` and handling its event. Is it that instance that you have displayed and raises the event? Almost certainly not. Where is the code that actually displays that form?

Comment: Also, your event code is rather bad. For one thing, there's no point checking whether any `ComponentPropertiesForm` instances are open. Just raise the event. If there's nothing to handle it then it won't be handled. Secondly, why on Earth have you declared that `status` parameter `ByRef`? Finally, that `status` parameter should not exist anyway, as ALL events should have `sender` and `e` arguments, with `e` being type `EventArgs`  or a derived type. You should [read this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: Think of your issue this way. Let's say that i have an iPhone and I set an alarm on it. If you get an iPhone too, will you be woken up by my alarm? Of course not, because your iPhone is a different object to my iPhone and the fact that one raises an alarm doesn't mean that every one does. They all act independently. Your forms are the same. Just because two forms are the same type does mean they are the same object, so one raising an event doesn't mean that every one does.

Comment: interesting article jmcilhinney, but it does not say anything about creating the "listeners". I've seen so many completely different examples of event handling (including the microsoft example I linked to) that I really don't know what is right. I'll keep plugging away. or just tell my users they have to refresh one form after closing the other

Comment: when you tell me *where* excatly ComponentPropertiesForm and MapComponentForm is shown, I can give you a working example